# RavenDB Search extension method

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

This test fails (using raven db extension method search, which allow multple parameters):

```
Db.Query<KeywordsSearchIndex.Result, KeywordsSearchIndex>()
              .Search(r => r.Value, "My Test String")
              .Count().Should().Be(1);
```

This passes (using standard where):

```
Db.Query<KeywordsSearchIndex.Result, KeywordsSearchIndex>()
              .Where(r => r.Value.Equals("My Test String"))
              .Count().Should().Be(1);
```

Why? It shoudl work accroding to the [docs](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/searching)

Comment: Do you have an index defined on the `KeywordsSearchIndex.Value` string, to indicate that it is analyzed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `KeywordsSearchIndex` do? What do you put it for as a second parameter? Probably you just get an empty collection from the `Query<KeywordsSearchIndex.Result, KeywordsSearchIndex>()`.